# Wordpress Contact form - Gmail issue

Tags: wordpress, email, gmail

I am using [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) on wordpress. When using any other email account apart form my gmail account in the to: address(where users send their queries to), I get the emails. just not gmail that is not receiving my form emails...

Why is that?

I am just using that plugin and no other mail/smtp plugins...

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your Gmail spam folder

Comment: try another gmail address instead of yours.

Answer (score 1):

> .. just not gmail that is not receiving my form emails... Why is that?

Because Gmail refuses to accept an email destined for a Gmail user, claiming to be from a Gmail user, delivered without authentication. That is, delivered through a server other than smtp.gmail.com.

It's Spam rules are (correctly) denying your 'forged' sender address.

> When using any other email account apart form my gmail account [...] I
>   get the emails

Obviously accounts that aren't Gmail have no way of verifying if the Gmail address is the true sender, so they have no grounds to reject the email.

You HAVE to use an SMTP plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/